# Is it possible to specify an order to an unordered_map?

Tags: c++

Is there really no guaranteed order in an unordered_map? I ask this because I would like to specify an order for an `unorderded_map`, so that it is possible to iterate the container from `begin()` to `end()` according to the specified order (while preserving the efficiency of an hashed access to single elements, globally speaking).

Comment: Obviously naming the type `unordered_map` was not enough to get the message across...

Comment: Look into [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).  I'm not familiar with it enough to tell give you an example, but I'm pretty sure if the solution to your problem is anywhere, it's there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know, it has its name for a reason...

To actually give it an order, you'd need to implement your own hash that somehow gives you the wanted order.

Now, for a solution to your actual problem, you can just create a `std::map` from your `std::unordered_map`, and even with minimal overhead for the insert (no copies):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
    m[5] = 1;
    m[4] = 2;
    m[3] = 3;
    m[2] = 4;
    m[1] = 5;
    typedef std::reference_wrapper<const int> cref_int;
    typedef std::reference_wrapper<int> ref_int;
    std::map<cref_int, ref_int> ordered(m.begin(), m.end());
    for(auto it=ordered.begin(), ite=ordered.end(); it != ite; ++it){
        std::cout << it->second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: And does it guarantee a guaranteed order for a particular hash implementation? I doubt it.

Comment: @jpalecek: Maybe you can somehow create a hashing algorithm specifically suited to your needs that somehow gives the wanted result? :P Notice the "somehow"s.

Comment: @Xeo: how would that hashing algorithm order colliding hashes? And what happens when the container is resized and rehashed?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: It's quite possible when you know what the keys are.  For instance, if all 10 keys are distinct values between 0 and 11, it's trivial to make a sorting hash.

Comment: The hashing algorithm alone doesn't help you, because you don't know what the container actually *does* with the hash value. The standard library's requirement is for a hash function that returns a `size_t`, but the map will typically chop this into something that corresponds to the bucket count.

Answer (score 5):

Of course not. If you need an order, use the regular map.