# Ordering in unordered_map in C++

Tags: c++

So I have an array as :

```
arr[] = {5, 2,4,2,3,5,1};
```

How can I insert them in this order with the number of times they occur in unordered_map?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void three_freq(int arr[], int n){
    unordered_map<int, int> m;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        m[arr[i]]++;
    }

    for(auto itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); itr++){
        cout<<itr->first<<":"<<itr->second<<"\n";
    }

}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {5, 2,4,2,3,5,1};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);
    three_freq(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Using the code above I am getting output as :

```
1:1
3:1
4:1
5:2
2:2
```

But I want the output to be in same order as the element occur in array.
Example:

```
5:2
2:2
4:1
3:1
1:1
```

Comment: You need different container for this. The unordered map is not sorted by default.

Comment: Do you care about the complexity of your solution?

Comment: @MyClass can you explain more, I am new to these map functions.

Comment: @Flut, `unordered_map` and you say you _want the output to be in same **order**_. Don't you see the contraddiction?

Comment: @KyleL  Not much, if it works.

Comment: `unordered_map` uses a hash_fn, so ordering is not guaranteed. You would need an ordered map, a.k.a `map` instead of `unordered_map`. Same API, you would need to replace `#include <unordered_map>` with `#include <map>` and `unordered_map<int,int>` to `map<int, int>`

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` ??

Comment: @Enlico but there are only two options either map or unordered map. Map directly sorts them so I am trying this one.

Comment: @fadedreamz its working, but getting sorted in ascending order. But I want them in a  particular order.

Comment: As the name suggests there is no particular order in an *un*ordered map. If you need order use `std::map`. Or for your case you could think about creating a vector from the map and then sort this vector.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want the output to match with the input order. Maybe use another `unordered_set` to check. Also, if you know the maximum value of the input and it's not sparse, then you can use a plain old array for efficiency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to specify an order to an unordered\_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497630/is-it-possible-to-specify-an-order-to-an-unordered-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about efficiency (that much), then you can just change the for loop which is printing the output.

```
for(int i=0; m.size(); i++) {
   auto it = m.find(arr[i]); 
   if (it != m.end()) {
      cout<<arr[i]<<":"<<it->second<<"\n";
      m.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the efficiency, now that I look at your code. You even have an early out when it's done.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking that the `erase` operation would take `theta(log(n)) or theta(n)`. But CPP ref shows its constant or amortized constant for the iterator version.

Answer (score 2):

You need unordered_map to do the counting efficiently, so keep that.

When printing out according to the order in another container, it makes sense to simply iterate over that other container for your output loop.

(Note that this is a completely separate operation, so it could have been a different function.)

```
// loop over the original array (recommend std::vector)
// exit early if done (stole from fadedreamz)
for (int index = 0; !m.empty(); ++index) {
    int number = arr[index];
    // check to see if we need to print this number
    // use contains if you have c++20
    if (m.count(number)) {
        std::cout << number << ":" << m[number] << std::endl;
        m.erase(number); // print only once by deleting the entry
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working too.

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me.

Comment: Updated with fadedreamz's early exit. Same worst case, but the early exit can be a big help on some data sets. Our code is pretty similar now that I've looked at it.

Answer (score 2):

The quite efficient way is traversing the original array and resetting the counters after print.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  if (m[a[i]]) != 0) {
    std::cout <<arr[i] << ":" << m[a[i]] << std::endl;
    m[a[i]] = 0;
  }
}
```